# Java-like static class & method in Python

Tags: java, python, static

I am new to Python and I am trying to implement something similar to the idea of "static" in Java. I tried multiple ways in Python (staticmethod, global etc.) but still can't quite get it working... Perhaps I was misunderstanding them in some ways...

In general what I am trying to do are:

- To have a list of static variables that are shared by other classes, say:

  - Names of the people in the room
  - Name of the person who is using the computer
  - Name of the last person who was using the computer
- To have static functions/callbacks for updating those variables, say:

  - Someone arrives/exits the room (Add/remove the name from the names of the people in the room)
  - Change the name of the person who is the current user of the computer

So from other classes, I want to access those variables and make decision based on their values, say:

```
class something():
 boolean IsComputerAvailable():
  if (Name of the person who is using the computer) == null:
   return true
  else:
   return false
```

or something like this... So what is the best way to do it in Python?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand the whole idea of persons in a room using computers, but this is an example of static attribute/method in python :

```
class Test():

    static_attr1 = 2

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(v):
        Test.static_attr1 = v
```

Then this code :

```
o1 = Test()
o2 = Test()

print "o1 static_attr : ", o1.static_attr1
print "o2 static_attr : ", o2.static_attr1

Test.static_method(3)

print "o1 static_attr : ", o1.static_attr1
print "o2 static_attr : ", o2.static_attr1
```

will print :

```
o1 static_attr : 2
o2 static_attr : 2
o1 static_attr : 3
o2 static_attr : 3
```

Comment: I think your `staticmethod` really is a disguised `classmethod`.